# Making a Queue Push_Back and Pop_Front with a Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue, doubly-linked-list

So I'm trying to create a Queue with a Linked List but I'm having trouble with my insert (which acts as push_back) and my erase (which acts as pop_front) apparently the insert and erase doesn't want to work they they are supposed to.

```
    #ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
    #define LINKEDLIST_H

    using namespace std;

    template <class T>
        struct Node {
                T value;
                Node<T> *next;
                Node<T> *prev;
                Node() : value(T()), next(NULL), prev(NULL) {}
                Node(T v) : value(v), next(NULL), prev(NULL) {}
                T getValue() { return value; }
                void setValue(T v) { value = v; }
        };

    template <class T>
        class LinkedList {
            private:
                Node<T> *header;
            public:
                LinkedList() {
            header = new Node<T>();
            header->next = header;
            header->prev = header;
        }
        ~LinkedList() {
            while (header->next != header->next)
               delete header;
        }

        void insert(T n) {
            Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>(n);
            newNode->prev = header;
            newNode->next = header->next;
            newNode->next->prev = newNode;
            header->next = newNode;
        }

        void erase() {
            header->next->prev->next = header->next->next;
            header->next->next->prev = header->next->prev;
            delete header->next;
        }

        Node<T> *begin() { return header->next; }
        Node<T> *end() { return header; }
    };
    #endif // LINKEDLIST_H
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using a [std::queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue)? It can wrap either a deque or a list.. (i.e, `std::queue<T, std::list<T>>` )

Comment: I'm trying to make the queue with the list

Comment: @Astor *the insert and erase doesn't want to work they they are supposed to.* -- So how do they work now?  A little more description would help.  Also, let's see the program that exercises your linked list.  Right now, I can easily come up with a program that would make your code faulty due to missing user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: I tried putting the queue into a radix sort, but only the first value was changed when the program ran. I changed the queue implementation to the std list and then it worked.

Comment: `while (header->next != header->next)` is utterly doomed. How can it not be equal to itself?